# MySQL Aggreation query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following mySQL code:

```
SELECT 
      c.categoryId, 
      c.categoryName, c.categoryParent, 
      c.categoryDescription, 
      COUNT(p.productid) as totalProdsInCategory
    FROM categories as c
     LEFT JOIN normalproducts as p 
     ON c.categoryId = p.categoryid
WHERE c.categoryId = 41
    GROUP BY c.categoryId
    ORDER BY c.categoryParent ASC,  c.categoryName ASC
```

I want to be able to include another COUNT column. But this must only be counted as as the products with p.state = "active". Here's my INCORRECT solution

```
SELECT 
      c.categoryId, 
      c.categoryName, c.categoryParent, 
      c.categoryDescription, 
      COUNT(p.productid) as totalProdsInCategory, 
      COUNT(q.productid) as totalActiveProdsInCategory
    FROM categories as c
     LEFT JOIN normalproducts as p 
     ON c.categoryId = p.categoryid
WHERE c.categoryId = 41
    GROUP BY c.categoryId
    ORDER BY c.categoryParent ASC,  c.categoryName ASC
```

Any help? I have no idea where to go from here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SUM (CASE WHEN p.state = "active" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` to get the count you're looking for.

```
SELECT 
      c.categoryId, 
      c.categoryName, c.categoryParent, 
      c.categoryDescription, 
      COUNT(p.productid) as totalProdsInCategory, 
      SUM (CASE WHEN p.state = "active" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalActiveProdsInCategory
    FROM categories as c
     LEFT JOIN normalproducts as p 
     ON c.categoryId = p.categoryid
WHERE c.categoryId = 41
    GROUP BY c.categoryId
    ORDER BY c.categoryParent ASC,  c.categoryName ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      c.categoryId, 
      c.categoryName, c.categoryParent, 
      c.categoryDescription, 
      COUNT(p.productid) as totalProdsInCategory, 
      SUM(IF(p.state='active',1,0)) as totalActiveProdsInCategory
    FROM categories as c
     LEFT JOIN normalproducts as p 
     ON c.categoryId = p.categoryid
WHERE c.categoryId = 41
    GROUP BY c.categoryId
    ORDER BY c.categoryParent ASC,  c.categoryName ASC
```

This is similar to @Conrad's but a little cleaner in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

This works but maybe doesn't align with the left join approach so much:

```
SELECT        
c.catId,c.catName,
COUNT(p.productId) as totalProdsInCategory,
(SELECT count(*) from product as p where p.catId=1 AND p.state='active') as totalActive
FROM cat as c      
LEFT JOIN product as p ON c.catId = p.catId 
WHERE c.catId = 1     
GROUP BY c.catId     
ORDER BY c.catName ASC
```